# Convert 2D Array Into 1D Array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this 2 dimensional array:

```
var list = [
    ['zone_1', 'zone_2'],
    ['zone_3']
]
```

I want to merge all elements in the sub-arrays into a single array:

```
var list = [
    'zone_1',
    'zone_2',
    'zone_3'
]
```

How can I do that in node.js?
It is possible to do it without using a loop or map?

Comment: `I don't want to use loop or map` Why not? Handy language tools are there to be used. An easy single-depth flatmap can be done via `const output = [].concat(...input.map(arr => arr));`

Comment: You can also find what you want at here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: What about using `list[0]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The array `.concat` method is variadic, and you can use the spread operator to pass each sub-array to it as a separate argument. This makes flattening an array turn into a nice one-liner:

```js
const arr = [ ['zone_1', 'zone_2'], ['zone_3'] ];
console.log([].concat(...arr))
```

Comment: Thank you very much CRice. It works now. It is the one that I wanted.

Answer (score 7):

Array.prototype.flat()
The flat() method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth.

```
const arr = [ ['zone_1', 'zone_2'], ['zone_3'] ];
console.log(arr.flat());
```